Asymptotic stability and Lyapunov functions
I fail to understand a passage in the proof of the following theorem (right after the definition that gives the context of my question):
(Definition of Lyapunov function)

Let $\Omega$ be a neighbourhood of $x_0$, and let $\Lambda \in C^1(\Omega)$ be a function with an isolated minimum at $x_0$ (assume$\Lambda(x_0) = 0$). If for the field $w(x)$ of system $\dot{x}=w(x)$ we have that $w(x) \cdot \nabla \Lambda(x) \leq 0$,$\forall x \in \Omega$, then $\Lambda$ is a Lyapunov function for the system.

Theorem:

If $w(x) \cdot \nabla\Lambda(x) < 0$, $x \neq x_0, x \in \Omega$, then $x_0$ is asymptotically stable.

Proof:

Consider the sets $A_{\epsilon} = \{x \in \Omega | \Lambda(x) \leq \epsilon \}$.
Then $A_{\epsilon^{'}} \subset A_\epsilon$ if $\epsilon^{'}<\epsilon$ and moreover $diam(A) \rightarrow 0$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. Since along the trajectories of $\dot{x}=w(x)$ $\dot{\Lambda} < 0$, any trajectory originating in $\Omega$ must cross the boundary $\partial A_\epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ decreasing. If the point tends to $\partial A_{\epsilon*}$ for some $\epsilon ∗> 0$, we would have $\dot{\Lambda}≤ −\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 0$ and $\forall t > 0$, which cannot hold; indeed, this would yield $\Lambda \rightarrow −\inf$, contradicting the hypothesis that $\Lambda(x_0) = 0$ is a minimum.

What I don't understand is why, if the point does not tend to $x_0$ and orbits  close to $\partial A_{\epsilon*}$, this implies that $\dot\Lambda$ is always $\leq \alpha$. Can't an orbit exist so that $\dot\Lambda$ stays negative but always decreases in magnitude, so that $\Lambda$ is always greater that some positive value, like the function $f(t)=\frac{1}{t} + c$ for $t \rightarrow \infty$?
Note: the case of Lyapunov stability for $w(x) \cdot \Lambda(x)$
≤ $0$ is proven separately, maybe this is used in this proof but I cannot see how.

Do you have a typo? In the theorem, is it $w (x) \cdot \Lambda (x)$ or $w (x) \cdot \color{red}{\nabla} \Lambda (x)$?

yes, there's a typo in the book. it's clearly a gradient. otherwise the dot product would not make sense. thanks! @K.Jiang

That is not possible because on any closed annulus $\overline B_{\epsilon_1}(x_0)\setminus B_{\epsilon_2}(x_0)$ with $\epsilon_2<\epsilon_1$, $\Lambda'(t)\le -\alpha$ for some $\alpha>0$ (here $B_r(a)$ stands For the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $a$).
This is a property of continuous functions: they attain their minimum/maximum on any compact, so a negative function will be bounded below by some negative constant. So $\Lambda$ will decrease at least with the negative rate $-\alpha$ inside the annulus, and the trajectory is forced to leave it through the inner boundary. BTW I think it is easier to do the proof using balls than using sublevel sets $A_{\epsilon}$. Just consider a family of balls with radii $r_n=1/n$ centered at $x_0$ and use the same argument.

thank you. but in this case $\dot\Lambda$ is not a function of the annulus $B_{\epsilon_1}(x_0)\setminus B_{\epsilon_2}(x_0)$ but of the path $x(t)$ which could sit entirely in the annulus $\forall t$ (this is what we are trying to disprove). Neither the annulus (because it is not closed) or the path (because it extends indefinitely $\forall t$) are closed, hence not compact. We may "fix" the annulus changing its definition a little, but definitely I don't see why, as a function of the path, $\dot\Lambda$ cannot behave as the derivative of $f(t)=\frac{1}{t} + c$.

$x(t)$ cannot sit entirely in the annulus because $\Lambda’$ is strictly negative inside, so it must abandon the annulus eventually and thus converges towards the minimum.

The annulus is indeed closed.

sorry @GReyes I don't understand. How do you define the sets $B_{\epsilon}$? I don't see why the annulus is closed, as it seems to me the difference of two closed sets. That said, $\Lambda^{'}=\frac{d}{dt}(\Lambda(x(t))$ is a function of $t$ (or of the path $x(t)$) but both are not compact ($t$ goes to $\infty$) as I wrote in my first comment, so I don't see how you can apply Weierstrass theorem (if I understood correctly your point). thanks for the patience!

I mean the set ${x: \epsilon_2\le ||x-x_0||\le\epsilon_1}$, a closed annulus. You are right that it is not the difference of closed or open balls, should have been more precise there.

It does not matter that $t$ takes values in a non-compact set. As long as $x(t)$ is in the closed annulus, $\Lambda’(t)=\nabla \Lambda(x(t))\cdot w(x(t))$ is below some negative constant.

thanks. I see now that the field $w$ allows to write $\Lambda^{'}$ as a function of $x$ as well. the fact that it is always strictly negative implies the traversal of any boundary.
